# How to isolate the non recurring one in a double variables output?

Tags: python

what would be the most pythonic way to go from:

```py
messages = 'red; blue,green; red,beige; red,red; yellow'
```

to:

```py
messages = 'blue,green,beige,yellow'
```

Comment: not sure the code is really usefull to answer this question ... I shared possible outputs and how I am looking to format. Just want to confirm if it is better to do a loop or if I should do another way

Comment: Why don't you just output `"xxx"`?

Comment: Please clarify what is the problem. It's not at all clear what the basic setup is – is "a code" outputting all of the options at once, is the updated output supposed to be per result or for all of them, are there always two elements to the output and are the elements always known strings, ...? Currently, the only thing we can say is that if you want the output to be ``'xxx'``... then ``return 'xxx'``.

Comment: Your description is totally inadequate, so if there isn't any code, I don't think you'll be getting any answers.  You need to remember none of us can read your mind, and we have no idea what your inputs and outputs are.

Comment: I updated my code above hope that helps

Comment: So you are looking for the set intersection across the ``;`` separated elements of all lines? It is still hard to tell what you need – the code is not runnable (e.g. there is no ``message`` defined) and it needlessly relies on unavailable data and apis. Please check the [mcve] help page – you should ideally just provide a sample of the data as a literal in the question itself, without requiring any system specific api calls to retrieve.

Comment: Ah, my bad, looks as if you are looking for the *set difference* of each line to the *set intersection* of all lines, is that correct? I.e. remove the parts that occur in all lines.

Comment: message is just how I name a given email in my code. I provided how the output looks 'red; xxx' or 'xxx; red'. With 'xxx' being a color not equal to 'red' it can be blue , green, .... I am looking to filter out my output to obtain ONLY this second color which is not always the same unlike the 'red' one

Comment: And ``red`` occurs in every message? Can there be messages as ``red; red`` and what should they be reduced to?

Comment: maybe it is easier to see it that way: `print('red; green')` /// `print('blue; red')`
lets assume that those print can be both of my potential outputs how can I convert them into `green` /// `blue` of course /// is not part of the code it's just there to split both case where red is the first value or second one

Comment: not possible to have a 'red; red'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233968/discussion-between-matarus-and-mistermiyagi).

Comment: I am looking to reduce it to `green` or `blue` assuming both of my print() examples above
I want to remove/filter out the 'red' recurring variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code seems to do exactly what I am looking for!

```py
messages.replace('red','').replace(';','').replace(' ','')
```

Answer (score -1):

IIUC, you want to split the string at semicolons and then filter the resulting category list:

```py
cat_string = 'red; xxx'

# split at ';', remove whitespace at the start/end of the string
# Result: ['red', 'xxx']
categories = [c.strip() for x in cat_string.split(';')]
```